# Nokogiri strip all attributes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this html markup:

```
<div class="item"><a href="www"></a></div>
```

and I'd like to get this:

```
<div><a></a></div>
```

How can I do it with Nokogiri?

Comment: What have you written? We can help you better by working from the code you wrote, than for us to start from scratch, write code that has absolutely no relation to what you have, and you have to force our suggestions into place.

Comment: @theTinMan, I was trying to do it through xpath, but thanks to my rather restricted knowledge of it I didn't know I could use splat. And I thought there may be special Nokogiri function that I missed in my google searhes, so I decided not to write down my research this time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="item"><a href="www"></a></div>')
```

1. You could remove all attributes by `xpath`:

   ```
   doc.xpath('//@*').remove
   ```
2. Or, if you ever need to do something more complex, sometimes it's easier to traverse all elements with:

   ```
   doc.traverse do |node| 
     node.keys.each do |attribute|
       node.delete attribute
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

That works for all but xml namespace attributes (xmlns=).  you can easily strip those off too via doc.remove_namespaces!  (include the exclamation point, otherwise it won't really remove them)